# Store data on data attribute and use it with Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, variables

I'm building a Wordpress website.

In one of the page I have an Ajax call to load more posts with a button inside a loop. To connect the loop with Ajax I store some variables inside a div tag on the same page.

Here is part of the code on the php page where I store the variables:

```
<div id="loader" class="js-ajax-response"
   data-current-post-type='<?php echo $current_post_type ?>'
   data-current-term-id='<?php echo $current_term_id ?>'
   data-posts-myajax='<?php echo serialize( $loop->query_vars ) ?>'
   data-current-page-myajax='1'
   data-max-page-myajax='<?php echo $loop->max_num_pages ?>'
   data-ajax-url='<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>wp-admin/admin-ajax.php'
></div>
```

The JS code to load more posts with Ajax:

```
if (document.querySelector('.js-btn-load-more')) {

    const el = document.querySelector("#loader");
    
    const current_post_type = el.dataset.currentPostType;
    const current_term_id = el.dataset.currentTermId;
    const posts_myajax = el.dataset.postsMyajax;
    const current_page_myajax = el.dataset.currentPageMyajax;
    const max_page_myajax = el.dataset.maxPageMyajax;
    const ajax_url = el.dataset.ajaxUrl;

    const loaderBtn = document.querySelectorAll('.js-btn-load-more');

    var i;
    for( i = 0; i < loaderBtn.length; i++ ){
        loaderBtn[i].addEventListener('click', function(){

            let button = this;
            const containerResponse = document.querySelector(".js-ajax-response");
            const data = new FormData();

            data.append( 'action', 'load_archive' );
            data.append( 'archive_post_type', current_post_type );
            data.append( 'taxonomy_term_id', current_term_id );
            data.append( 'query', posts_myajax );
            data.append( 'page', current_page_myajax );

            fetch(ajax_url, {
            method: "POST",
            body: data
            })
            .then((response) => response.text())
            .then((data) => {
            if (data) {
                containerResponse.innerHTML += data;
                locoScroll.update();
                button.style.display = "block";
                
                current_page_myajax++;

                if ( current_page_myajax == max_page_myajax )
                button.style.display = "none"; // If last page, remove the button
            }
            })
            .catch((error) => {
            });
        });
    };
}
```

The issue is, when I click the button to load more posts, it always load the same posts.

Let me know if you need the entire code of the PHP loop.

Thank you.

Comment: Well, do you have any functionality to update the variables in the "loader" element with the latest ones, each time after you have loaded more content? I don't see anything like that. So obviously it's inevitable that it will keep loading the same posts, because you are never telling it anything different.

Comment: @ADyson `current_page_myajax++`  is there. They are trying to update but there's a mistake because it's a constant.

Comment: @Popnoodles that's a `const` though, so it's not updatable! https://jsfiddle.net/s5fw0gb8/

Comment: @Popnoodles ah you edited your comment and beat me to it! :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your console for errors...

You've set this constant

`const current_page_myajax = el.dataset.currentPageMyajax;`

but you are trying to update it.

`current_page_myajax++;`

That will just produce an error.

Use

`let current_page_myajax = el.dataset.currentPageMyajax;`

or for compatibility with older browsers

`var current_page_myajax = el.dataset.currentPageMyajax;`

[const](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const)

> The const declaration creates block-scoped constants, much like variables declared using the let keyword. The value of a constant can't be changed through reassignment (i.e. by using the assignment operator), and it can't be redeclared (i.e. through a variable declaration). However, if a constant is an object or array its properties or items can be updated or removed.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Popnoodles It seems I didn't pay enough attention how to declare the variable : )